# ForceBuild Cruisecontrol.net using batch file

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to trigger a force build on a project inside cruisecontrol.net using a batch file?????

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [URL Trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Url+Trigger), but as Joseph said, your machine with the batch file would need to modify a web page that the build machine checks.  This could be a file on the build machine itself, modified by your batch file.

Answer (score 1):

If your local machine has visibility to the web site that CC.NET run's on the build machine, I would imagine you could write a batch file that would execute the url command on whatever project you want which effectively just presses the "Force Build" button.  Just issue whatever request the "Force Build" button does on that page.

I would give you some code, but I don't have my server box up at the moment so I can't see what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple URL, the buttons send a form via POST. However, there's a command line utility that will be included in 1.5 to perform such tasks.